# Не создается экземпляр класса

Tags: java, android

Создаю экземпляр класса

```
public class AddFragment extends Fragment {

private DataBaseHelper myDb;
private Button writeButton, deleteButton;
private EditText namePassEdit, emailEditText, pasEditText, informationEditText;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_add_fragment, null);
    initializeViews(rootView);

    return rootView;
}

private void initializeViews(View rootView){
    namePassEdit = rootView.findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);
    emailEditText = rootView.findViewById(R.id.emailEditText);
    pasEditText = rootView.findViewById(R.id.passwodEditText);
    informationEditText = rootView.findViewById(R.id.infoEditText);

    writeButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.writeButton);
    /*deleteButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.delButton);
    deleteButton.setVisibility(rootView.GONE);*/

    writeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PassClass passClass = new PassClass();
            passClass.setName(namePassEdit.getText().toString());
            passClass.setEmail(emailEditText.getText().toString());
            passClass.setPassword(pasEditText.getText().toString());
            passClass.setInfo(informationEditText.getText().toString());
            if (new DBAdapter(getActivity()).savePass(passClass)){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Not Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

}

public void writeToSql(){

}
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
}}
```

Есть идентичный фрагмент, который создается без проблем, вызываются фрагменты через общую функцию

```
private void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Посмотрел в режиме отладке, увидел следующие. Думаю, что проблема в этом. Что это такое и как от этого избавится 
[image: режим отладки]

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите, какое значение Вы передаёте в переменную

```
Fragment fragment
```

в методе

```
private void setFragment(Fragment fragment){}
```

и сравните с той переменной, которую вы передаёте при вызове setFragment(), где этот метод работает правильно. А вообще, Вы должны передавать новый инстанс фрагмента -

```
setFragment(new YourFragmentName());
```

P.s  Дополните FragmentTransaction вот так:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.main_frame, fragment);
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```